# NSArray losing value at the end of method

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have a project I am working on, to learn some more about JSON and restkit. It all is working great, however I am having trouble with an array losing it's values.

This is the last method that is executed in my network request.

```
SHRetrieveStoresWS.m

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
  self.stores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
  StoresViewController *viewController = [[StoresViewController alloc] init];
  [viewController didLoadObjects:objects];


  for (Store *aStore in stores) {
      NSLog(@"%@", [aStore longName]);

  }


}
```

Which calls this method in my view controller.

```
StoresViewController.m

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *data;


- (void)didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)aArray
{

    NSLog(@"%d", aArray.count);
    self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:aArray];
    NSLog(@"%d", data.count);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The values are correct when I ask for the values within this method, but the array shows 0 objects immediately afterwards. Am I missing something here?

I am later checking the value with this method.

```
- (IBAction)pushMe:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Data: %d", self.data.count);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling any array initializer in viewDidLoad? What could be  happening is you're setting the array on the newly initialized view controller, then when viewDidLoad gets called, it could be wiping that array with a new initialization.

Comment: Do you have an `@synthesize data;` line in the implementation section of your view controller?

Comment: I do have it an @synthesize data; line. I don't have the array initialized in viewDidLoad, to avoid that very issue.

Comment: @Ryan Good. One more basic qn just to eliminate obvious things (sorry):  do you have `data` declared as an ivar in the @interface block?  (or did you just "declare" it with @property?)  The reason for these simple qns is that you are assigning `self.data` (i.e., via the property) but then accessing it as `data.count` (i.e., via the ivar).

Comment: @Turix BTW, 1. `@synthesize` is no longer needed. It's optional, and if you omit it, it's equivalent to having done `@synthesize data = _data;` 2. I certainly hope he has _not_ also defined an ivar for `data` as that's no longer considered best practice ... it will be synthesized for you and if you define one, it's only a source of possible rendundant ivars; 3. But you're point re `data.count` is valid. You want to make sure you don't have an extra ivar sitting around (hence my second point).

Comment: @Rob That's actually why I asked.  See my followup and note that the ivar he is accessing to get the count is `data` and not `_data`, nor the property `self.data`.

Comment: @Turix I changed them to match, but still seeing the same issue.

Comment: @Ryan OK.  It was worth a shot.  Thank for reporting back.  Sorry it wasn't something "simple" like this, but good luck figuring it out.  (Personally, I'm stumped from the info you've provided so far.)  One last ditch thing to try though:  Change the `NSLog` to use `self.data.count`... just in case!  ;-)

Comment: @Rob In the first block of code, it is taking the returned array "objects" and passing it through to other method, where I set initialize data with the contents of objects. At this point the array shows to have the proper number of objects, in this case 6. Immediately after this though, it shows 0.

Comment: @Ryan I'm with Turix, that I'd be concerned that you have an ivar defined somewhere, given that you're using the setter accessor method to set `data`, but then using some ivar called `data` that may or may not refer to the same object. Don't define ivars for your properties and it eliminates possible confusion there. That's the only obvious candidate for what's going on (other than noa's concern that you might be allocating another view controller).

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the input, I'll take a closer look at how everything is defined.

Comment: Ryan, what do you mean by "immediately after" -- do you mean aArray.count logs 6 and data.count logs 0, or is it after didLoadObjects, the data has a zero count?

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry for the confusion, wrong choice of words. Both of the NSLogs within my didLoadObjects method show the correct count. It is after that, that the trouble starts.

Comment: So then how and where are you seeing the count of zero? You should post the method where you see it become zero. Are you logging it as zero, or just inferring that because your table view is empty?

Comment: @rdelmar I added the code for when I check the value of the count of the array. It is tied to a button on the navigation bar.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause this problem. It isn't clear to me from the discussion above what you've done with declaring ivars and using @synthesize. If you've done either of those you should get rid of them. You only need to declare the property -- make sure you don't have something called data somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're presenting this view controller? Is it from a segue, or are you calling `presentViewController...` somewhere?

Comment: @ryanwils I am using a segue to present this view controller.

Comment: Ah! That's the issue then. You should be using the prepareForSegue method to pass any data in. I'll write up some code as an answer to show you.

Comment: Added it, check it out and let me know if it works!

Comment: @ryanwils I really appreciate it, I'll give it a shot and let you know if it works out.

Comment: @Ryan No problem, any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the data in the segue...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"MY_IDENTIFIER"]){
        StoresViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [viewController didLoadObjects: objects];
    }
}
```

That should work for you! Just change MY_IDENTIFIER to whatever the identifier of your segue is.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! You can also accept the answer so others will see it easier if they stumble on the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! :) Best of luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you're creating multiple instances of StoresViewController instead of giving your network controller a reference to the *original* instance.

You can demonstrate it to yourself by printing out `self` in `-viewDidLoad` and again in `didLoadObjects:`. You'll see that the pointer addresses are different.

This line is the culprit:

```
StoresViewController *viewController = [[StoresViewController alloc] init];
```

Instead of instantiating StoresViewController again, add a property to your SHRetrieveStoresWS class and use it to hold a reference to your view controller.

```
@property (strong) StoresViewController *viewController;
```

You'll need to set that property before `-didLoadObjects:` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

StoresViewController is initialised as a local variable which is only accessible in the method that it was declared (aka objectLoader). After objectLoader has completed, the local variable is no longer valid.